# Problem in Repository Address

Tags: apt, repository

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 xenial on Lenovo z5070.
I'm trying to install rstudio on my laptop. The repository address of rstudio is:

```
http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/xenial/
```

but when I using this address, in `sudo apt-get update`, I faced with the following problem:

```
E: Malformed entry 55 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Suite)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

so for solving this problem, I changed the repository address to the following address:

```
http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
```

the problem was solved and `sudo apt-get update` was working fine, but for rstudio, I get the following warning:

```
The repository 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease' is not signed.
```

how can I fix this problem?

Tnx all,

Mansoor,

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with fetching the secure APT key:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9
gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
```

so for every package that I want to install, should I import the APT key?

Comment: please don't forget to always add the _repo key_ after adding the address to _source list_

Comment: where can I get the repo key for packages?

Comment: doing `sudo apt install rstudio` will also add the required key and entry in the _source list_, in you case you did it manually so would be also provided and you have to add it.

Comment: You can install `y-ppa-manager` for an easy way to update/maintain gpg keys.

Comment: how can I use it?